# How do I move data using update in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

Assuming I have a document...

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5c4cc127c33477ec8841d317"),
        "review_date" : "2019-01-26T04:07:43.345Z",
        "comment" : "decent product",
        "score" : 4,
        "reviewer_id" : "barry"
}
```

and I want to update it to be...

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5c4cc127c33477ec8841d317"),
        "review_date" : "2019-01-26T05:15:13.122Z",
        "comment" : "awesome product",
        "score" : 5,
        "reviewer_id" : "barry",
        "history" : [
                {
                        "review_date" : "2019-01-26T04:07:43.345Z",
                        "comment" : "decent product",
                        "score" : 4
                }
        ]
}
```

How would I change this?

In other words, move/copy some of the fields to another area of the document, and replace some existing fields with new values.  The purpose is to store history of change within the same document as an array - could be many review changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you plan on doing is add history. You can do this by using `db.collection.findOneAndUpdate` with $set in place.

An example with a collection name product would be:

```
db.products.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: ObjectId("5c4cc127c33477ec8841d317") }, {
  $set: {
    score: 5,
    history: [{
               "review_date" : "2019-01-26T04:07:43.345Z",
               "comment" : "decent product",
               "score" : 4
   }]
  }
})
```

Comment: This added a history, which is part of my question so kudos! but how do I update the primary review fields at the same time - or would it require two update statements?

Comment: Could this be accomplished with FindOneAndUpdate()?

Comment: You can also update the comment and score using this same query. I'll edit the example.

Comment: This is perfect!  Thank you!

Comment: By the way, is there a way I can refer to an existing field in my update statement so I don't use string literals, but rather a variable concept instead?  SQL example: Update mytable set myfield2 = myfield1 where myid = 123

Comment: The only way I know one could do this is using mongoose. It will be something like `db.collection.update(params).where(name).equals(value)`

Comment: Thanks @Ademola for the help!